# Can one JavaScript function handle different types of HTML input types?

Tags: javascript, html, coding-style

I have a question in regards to input, select elements.

If I have a `radio`, `text`, `select` elements on the page do I need to provide a single JavaScript function to handle their events or should I separate it so that each type has its own function but I would group text and date type into one function.

What's the best way to do this? Keep in mind I'm not using submit here as it's not needed in my case.

At the moment I have one function to handle radio inputs, one to handle text and dates and one to handle select elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my short time of programming, I have found using multiple JS functions to handle HTML events. Less bugs, and easier to manipulate each event. These functions can also call and manipulate one another. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Daebrion, yeah i thought the same but i just wanted to know what people prefer i think ill stick to this way then :) .Thanks for the answer.